# How can enclose X axis labels using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I want enclose my plot X axis labels as below picture using ggplot2 ?but i dont know how to do it,can you help me ?thank you very much .

[image: picture is here]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with enclosing? Wouldn't resizing the plot window bring the labels closer together?

Comment: what i want to do is red line enclose the  X axis labes.

Comment: Ok, you want a literal box (well, parallelogram) drawn around the labels. Hmmmm ... not sure if `ggplot2` is going to make that easy, you will likely need to dive into the grob manually ...

Comment: @r2evans I think it was just a box the OP wanted. You were right about getting the grob manually. Well, you can draw a rectange over it as a shortcut, but as soon as you resize the plot you'll get into trouble...

Comment: I was trying to be literal with the angled red lines, not assuming too much, I'm glad you had a good solution. Thanks @AllanCameron!

Answer (score 1):

You could just draw a rectangle over your plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars) %>%
  ggplot(aes(rowname, mpg)) + 
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "name")

grid::grid.rect(x = unit(32, "pt"), y = unit(5.5, "pt"), 
                height = unit(0.265, "npc"), width = unit(0.93, "npc"), 
                vjust = 0, hjust = 0, gp = grid::gpar(fill = NA))
```

[image]

However, a more robust way to do it so that the rectangle doesn't move relative to your plot when you rescale it is to convert the ggplot to a grobtree, find the grob that represents the area of the bottom axis, and overwrite its first member (which is a zeroGrob) with a rectGrob. You can then plot the whole thing with `grid::grid.draw`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

p <- tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars) %>%
  ggplot(aes(rowname, mpg)) + 
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "name")

p2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))

p2$grobs[[which(p3$layout$name == "axis-b")]]$children[[1]] <- 
  grid::rectGrob(gp = grid::gpar(fill = NA))

grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(p2)
```

[image]

Comment: It's so perfect ,Thank you very much !